# How to update table using select statement results in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to update a tabel where the value of field is equal the result of select statement.  I have a table like this:

```
Type     Total#
A           4
B           8
C           1
```

I want to update the above table based the result of a select statement.
Here is my code:

```
update MainTable
  set [Total#] = 
  (SELECT count(distinct r.[ID])as Type
  FROM dbo.TableA r left join
  dbo.TableB a
  on r.Post_ID = a.Post_ID
  where a.Status is null)
```

if i run the code as is, it is going to update all rows but i only want to update where Type from select statement is equal the Type from my MainTable.  thanks

Comment: what are the table structures for tableA and tableB?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give this a try,

```
UPDATE  x
SET     x.[Total#] = y.totalCount
FROM    MainTable x
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  [Type], COUNT(DISTINCT r.[ID]) totalCount
            FROM    dbo.TableA r
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.TableB a
                        ON r.Post_ID = a.Post_ID
            WHERE   a.STATUS IS NULL
            GROUP BY    [Type]
        ) y ON x.[Type] = y.[Type]
```

***PS: when asking question like this, please add the structure of the table. It helps a lot.***

Answer (score 0):

Give an alias to your `MainTable` and you can use it in the subquery:

```
update MainTable mt
   set [Total#] = (SELECT count(distinct r.[ID]) as Type
                     FROM dbo.TableA r 
                          left join dbo.TableB a on r.Post_ID = a.Post_ID
                    where a.Status is null
                      and a.AType = mt.AType )
 where mt.AType = @Value
```

Comment: thanks but i am getting this error: Must declare the scalar variable "@Value".

Comment: @moe The shown query is an example, if you don't need the where, remove it, or adjust the `@value` to a real value you want to filter with.